# Arduino - The port 'COM3' does not exist

Tags: asp.net, arduino, serial-port, port

I built a model with Arduino and I want the results of the sensors to be shown in my database.

My project is on my server and the Arduino is connected directly to my computer with USB.

The project is built on asp.net - Visual Studio 2017. When I'm running the program it gives me an error:

> The port 'COM3' does not exist

```
public void readSensor() {
  SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM3",9600);
  port.BaudRate = 9600;
  port.PortName = "COM3";
  port.Open();
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: you might have connected the arduino to wrong port. Check in device manager and find which is port 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very simple and common error in arduino. Once you have searched for a solution on google you might have came across the one you need.

This occurs when you connect the arduino to wrong port. Check in device manager and find which is port 3.

Make the connections perfect. That's it.